# Use sequential CASEs as parameters for larger CASE

Tags: mysql, sql, case

```
SELECT CASE
WHEN
    CASE
        WHEN `AA`>6
        THEN `A`
        ELSE NULL
    END,
    CASE
        WHEN `BB`>6
        THEN `B`
        ELSE NULL
    END,
    CASE
        WHEN `CC`>6
        THEN `C`
        ELSE NULL
    END
THEN `NAME`
END
FROM TABLE;
```

The goal of this query is to show the columns A through C and Name. but if A-C is null to not show NAME.
I'm new to CASEs and 'advanced' queries in general, so if I have this set up like a fool, feel free to let me know.

Thanks for reading.

**NOTE: doesn't compile**

The logic I'm trying to get is so:

```
if(
    if(AA>6) then 1 else 0
    OR
    if(BB>6) then 1 else 0
    OR
    if(CC>6) then 1 else 0
    etc,etc
   ) then 1 else 0
```

Table:

```
Name    A       B        C         AA   BB  cc
--------------------------------------------------------
Name1   Data1   null    Data3       3   n   15
Name2   null    Data2   Data4       n   2   8
Name3   null    Data2   Data4       n   2   2
```

Output wanted if it's only showing values gt 6:

```
 Name   A      B      C
 -------------------------
 Name1              Data3
 Name2              Data4
```

Comment: Why are you using AA,BB,CC,DD and so on?

Comment: I'm using them as comparison on to show the A,B,C,etc

Comment: This doesnt seem like it will compile at all. It is not very clear what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: are your column names A,B,C,D,E,F,G,Name?

Comment: You might have better luck if you include the schema, some sample rows, and the output you expect to see from those sample rows. Setting up a demo on sqlfiddle.com would make it even easier for people to help you.

Comment: Can you post some sample data and desired output?

Comment: why are you even trying to go near case when? you can simply filter in the where condition only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it

```
SELECT Name, 
       CASE WHEN aa > 6 THEN a END a,
       CASE WHEN bb > 6 THEN b END b,
       CASE WHEN cc > 6 THEN c END c
  FROM table1
 WHERE aa > 6
    OR bb > 6
    OR cc > 6
```

or

```
SELECT Name, 
       CASE WHEN aa > 6 THEN a END a,
       CASE WHEN bb > 6 THEN b END b,
       CASE WHEN cc > 6 THEN c END c
 FROM table1
HAVING COALESCE(a, b, c, -1) <> -1
```

In the second query `-1` is just a constant that will be returned if all of your columns have `NULL` values. You can use any value that will never be a part of your result set. In this particular case since you're applying `column > 6` condition to every column you can use any number that is less than `6`.

Output:

```
|  NAME |      A |      B |     C |
-----------------------------------
| Name1 | (null) | (null) | Data3 |
| Name2 | (null) | (null) | Data4 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d0f15/3)** demo

Comment: Thank you so much. This a lot neater then where I was going with this.
COALESCE is new to me, then again, so is HAVING, I'll be sure to read up on them.
SQLFiddle is new to me too, I'll be sure to use it.
Thanks again.

Comment: You're very welcome. Good luck :). FYI the second query will work only in MySql (because its `HAVING` extension allows to use aliases in `HAVING` clause) while the first one will work on any major RDBMS.